# How to extend plupload to ask the user for a title for the file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plupload, photo-upload

I'm using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php) to allow users to upload photos to my website, which works great.

I've been using the jQuery queue widget as well.

Now, is there any way i can ask the user to specify an (optional) title for each photo they upload? Currently my server method accepts just the filename, the chunk, and the content itself. I simply want another parameter for "photo title".

Of course, i can rip out the queue widget and write a custom widget with textboxes next to each photo, but was hoping there is an easier way, or a pre-built plugin/widget that enables this.

Any ideas/recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it in a 2 step process, after finishing the upload ask the user to enter the titles for the newly uploaded files or you should implement your own widget and add listeners to the various events of plupload to render the queue along with input elements to allow the user to enter titles.

Out of the box with the jquery widget it's not possible through simple configuration. You'll allways have to extend or implement a custom upload script.

Take a look at the [Custom upload example](http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php), you'll get an idea of how to render the elements on the plupload events and submit the values along.

Comment: Yeah, i really don't want to write my own widget. Not because it's hard or anything, but because the less custom code you have to write, the better. As you say im probably going to just let the user set the title post-upload.